# GDPR compliance in ads SDK for iOS/Android

Tags: android, ios, sdk

I work on a native ads SDK for iOS/Android (banner, interstitial, video ads etc.).
We want to comply with GDPR regulations (and others, like COPPA, later).

So I have few questions here:

1. Should the SDK provide a way (set of get/set functions) for publisher to read/write the GDPR data? I talk here about the values of `IABConsent_SubjectToGDPR`, `IABConsent_ConsentString`, `IABConsent_ParsedPurposeConsents` and `IABConsent_ParsedVendorConsents` in user defaults or shared preferences...
2. If yes then should the SDK parse the `IABConsent_ConsentString` and store the parsed data to `IABConsent_ParsedPurposeConsents` and `IABConsent_ParsedVendorConsents`?
3. Or, maybe the SDK should ask the user by itself for the consent data?
4. Even if none of the above has to be implemented in the SDK, it still has to read the GDPR related data from `NSUserDefaults`/`SharedPreferences`. So should it read the `IABConsent_ConsentString` and parse it by itself? Or can I just rely on the parsed values (`IABConsent_ParsedPurposeConsents` and `IABConsent_ParsedVendorConsents`)?
5. And, in general, who is responsible to collect this data from the user, build consent string and parse it to vendors and purposes lists? Is it the publisher (app developer) or each one who touches this data (e.g. SDKs in use)?

Thank you.

Comment: looks like your question is not for developers, but for lawyers.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I don't think that any lawyer can tell me whether an SDK or the app developer should parse the consent string..

Comment: more likely that no developer can know that.

Comment: I believe there are developers out there that have implemented it...

Comment: Lawyer can tell that user related data shouldn't be sent/stored in the server for EU users that haven't permitted it. I don't think there's a lawyer out there that can tell how to implement it..